# Usar la misma variable en dos funciones PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, funciones, variables

```
<?php require_once 'config.php';
// INICIA FUNCION 1
function saveInvoice( array $data){ 
    if( !empty( $data ) ){              
    global $con; 
    $count = 0; 
    if( isset($data['data'] )){

         foreach ($data['data'] as $value) {
                    if(!empty($value['length'] ))$count++;
                                }
        }
        if($count == 0)throw new Exception( "Please add atleast one item to warehouse form." );
        if( !empty( $data)){
          $codigo1 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['codigo1'] ) );
          $shipper = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['shipper'] ) );
          $codigo2 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['codigo2'] ) );
          $consignee = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['consignee'] ) );
          $carrier = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['carrier'] ) );
          $supplier = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['supplier'] ) );
          $tracking = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['tracking'] ) );
          $vlb_total = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['airtotal'] ) );
          $ft3_total = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['oceantotal'] ) );
          $weight_total = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['totalweight'] ) );
          $method = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['method'] ) );
          $user = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['user'] ) );
          $office = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['office'] ) );
          $notes = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['notes'] ) );
          $total_air_usd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['totalairusd'] ) );
          $total_ocean_usd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['totaloceanusd'] ) );                 
          $warehouse = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $data['warehouse'] ) );

         if(empty($warehouse)){
           $uuid = uniqid();
         $query = "INSERT INTO wreceipt (`warehouse`, `codigo1`, `shipper`, `codigo2`, `consignee`, `carrier`, `supplier`, `tracking`, `vlb_total`, `ft3_total`, `weight_total`, `method`, `user`, `office`, `notes`, `total_air_usd`, `total_ocean_usd`, `created`, `uuid`) VALUES ('', '$codigo1', '$shipper', '$codigo2', '$consignee', '$carrier', '$supplier', '$tracking', '$vlb_total', '$ft3_total', '$weight_total', '$method', '$user', '$office', '$notes', '$total_air_usd', '$total_ocean_usd', NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR, '$uuid')";
          }else{
             throw new Exception( "Please check, some of the required fields missing" );
            }
           if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
            throw new Exception(  mysqli_error($con) );
            }else{
           if(empty($warehouse))$warehouse = mysqli_insert_id($con);
             }

           if( isset( $data['data']) && !empty( $data['data'] )){
           saveInvoiceDetail( $data['data'], $warehouse );
                                }
           return [
                   'success' => true,
                   'uuid' => $uuid,
                   'message' => 'Warehouse Saved Successfully.',
                   'warehouse' => $warehouse
                ]; 
         }else{
            throw new Exception( "Please check, some of the required fields missing" );             }
          }else{
        throw new Exception( "Please check, some of the required fields missing" );         
    }
}
// FINALIZA FUNCION 1

//INICIA FUNCION 2        
    function saveInvoiceDetail(array $wreceipt_items, $warehouse = '')
    {
   global $con;

  foreach ($wreceipt_items as $wreceipt_item){
  $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['desc'] ) );
  $length = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['length'] ) );
  $width = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['width'] ) );
  $height = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['height'] ) );
  $weight = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['weight'] ) );
  $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['quantity'] ) );
  $volumeweight = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim($wreceipt_item['volumeweight'] ) );
  $volume = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $wreceipt_item['volume'] ) );
  $weightrow = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim($wreceipt_item['weightrow'] ) );

  $query = "INSERT INTO wreceipt_items (`id`, `warehouse`, `desc`, `length`, `width`, `height`, `weight`, `quantity`, `volumeweight`, `volume`, `weightrow`)
 VALUES (NULL, '$warehouse', '$desc', '$length', '$width', '$height', '$weight', '$quantity', '$volumeweight', '$volume', '$weightrow' )";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    }
     }
//FINALIZA FUNCION 2

//INICIA FUNCION 3                 
function getInvoices($warehouse){
  global $con;
  $data = [];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM wreceipt WHERE warehouse = '$warehouse'";
  if ( $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) ){
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           array_push($data, $row);
              }
         }    return $data; } ?>
//FINALIZA FUNCION 3
```

Este es el codigo entero, no consigo que el valor de la variable ***$warehouse* = mysqli_insert_id($con);** salga de la primera funcion para utilizarla en la segunda funcion, especficamente aqui: **$query = "SELECT * FROM wreceipt WHERE warehouse = '$*warehouse*'" ;**. Este query me da el ROW de "warehouse".. es lo que no consigo hacer. Alguna ayuda? Pagaria por la solucion, he hecho demasiados intentos para encontrar el modo en que funcione pero el valor de Warehouse pareciera que no sale de la funcion 1

getInvoices se muestra en otro documento php mas o menos asi:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'warehouse-save.php';

    $invoices = getInvoices($warehouse);

        if( !empty( $invoices ) ){ 
        foreach ($invoices as $value) {
        <?= $value['warehouse'] ?>
            } 
        }else{
        echo "No Invoice Found";
        }
?>
Pero el problema no debe ser aqui porque todo funciona bien cuando cambio la variable warehouse en el query por un valor fijo. POR EJEMPLO "SELECT * FROM wreceipt WHERE warehouse = 420 " ;**. (este funciona).
```

Comment: Te falta indicar en la función que ésta debe recibir la variable que le pasas en parámetro: `function getInvoices($warehouse){
...}` **Aviso de seguridad**: Tu código es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL, no escribas nunca consultas de este modo: `SELECT * FROM wreceipt WHERE warehouse = '$warehouse'`  , usa consultas preparadas: `SELECT * FROM wreceipt WHERE warehouse = ?` haciendo binding del valor `$warehouse`
.

Comment: es irrelevante, porque la funcion que recibe la variable recibe los resultados cuando sustituyo 'warehouse' por un valor fijo. Si estoy consciente de la inyeccion sql.

Comment: ¿Qué cosa es irrelevante? ¿La respuesta dada no ha resuelto tu problema? Combinando esa respuesta con consultas preparadas el código funcionará y será un código seguro, aplicando las normas recomendadas y buenas prácticas de programación.

Comment: ¿Tú comprobaste que en `$data`  hay algo llamado `wharehouse` haciendo por ejemplo `$var_dump($data);`  o bien `$print_r($data);`? Aparte de los problemas de seguridad ya mencionados, piensa en organizar mejor tu código, por ejemplo, preguntas si `$data` está vacío, pero antes de eso, intentas usar `$data`... eso es incorrecto, ¿no deberías preguntar antes que nada si data está vacío y luego tratar de usarlo?

Comment: A ver.. le bajamos un poquito a la arrogancia, acudo a este sitio para conseguir ayuda, no para recibir reganos por la organizacion del codigo.
De data no tiene warehouse ya que esa variable viene vacia hasta que aparece en este if **if(empty($warehouse))$warehouse = mysqli_insert_id($con);
                        }**
Alli se le asigna un valor INT en la base de datos y lo devuelve para utilizarlo en la siguiente funcion.

Comment: Amigo se te está tratando de ayudar, ahora bien, si eso lo interpretas como arrogancia me retiro del caso y que otro usuario te ayude. En un código mal organizado te pierdes, y parece ser tu caso. Sólo para revisarlo y ver una posible causa habría que sacarlo en un editor aparte y organizar todos los if que tienes por todas partes. En fin, espero que puedas resolver tu problema.

Comment: Por favor, tabula un poco el código para que sea más sencillo seguirlo. Por otro lado... en ese código no se está llamando a `getInvoices` en ningún lado

Comment: Hola @eferion Ya anadi lo que pediste

Answer (score 0):

Te falta indicar el parámetro en la función:

```
function getInvoices(){
//                   ^
```

El código debería parecerse más a esto:

```
function getInvoices($warehouse){
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

**Edito**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'warehouse-save.php';

$invoices = getInvoices($warehouse);
```

Esa variable `$warehouse` ¿Dónde la has declarado? En ese contexto es una variable global... sin embargo en tus funciones la estás usando como variable local.

No se, quizás bastaría con una solución tal que:

```
function saveInvoice( array $data){ 
  global $con;
  global $warehouse;
  // ...
}
```

Pero tendrás que probarlo a ver si te sirve... Eso sí, tendrás que asegurarte que antes de llamar a `getInvoices($warehouse)` has llamado a `saveInvoice()` o `$warehouse` no estará inicializada.

Comment: Hola eferion, olvide mencionar que tambien trate de ese modo y no funciono. No toma el valor de la variable de la otra funcion.

Comment: @IrvingNgr lo que esta escrito en esta respuesta debe de funcionarte. Verifica que no estas asignadole null a `$warehouse`

Comment: No funciona aun, no es null, la variable es guardada previamente en la primera funcion sin problemas pero al momento en que la quiero usar en la segunda funcion es como si no estuviera alli. PD: al sustituir la variable en el query por un valor fijo el codigo funciona.

Comment: @IrvingNgr "*No funciona aun, no es null*" ¿a qué te refieres? ¿qué no es null?

Comment: Me refiero a que no le estoy asignando NULL a "warehouse" edite el codigo y lo escribi completo. Estoy consciente de algunos fallos de seguridad y errores mejores pero el principal problema es que no puedo obtener el valor de esa variable

Comment: @IrvingNgr piensa que una buena estrategia para evitar errores tontos en PHP es tener el código bien organizado, limpio y legible. Dado que PHP no tiene tipado de variables y ni siquiera obliga a declararlas es fácil pensar que una variable va a tener un valor determinado cuando no es así